# using webkit-mask not working with Express

Tags: javascript, css, express, svg

I'm wondering if anyone has come across this problem where code served from Apache works but does not when served from Express.

The setup is supposed to have a logo (logo.svg) that masks rotating background images ("first.jpg" and "second.jpg").

My specific problem is with this code that renders fine on an Apache server, but the masked image ("logo.svg") does not render.

I've checked pathes (all good as in the same directory as background images). I've checked the SVG and it seems OK. I've tried to find other instances of this occurring but no luck.  No clues in console either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
      <div class="bg_item"></div>
      <div id="fader" class="bg_item"></div>
 </div>
<div id="svg">  </div>
```

JS:

```
var fader = document.getElementById("fader");
var timer = setInterval(switcher, 3000);

function switcher() {
    fader.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

CSS:

```
#svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    color: linear-gradient(358deg, #dd851e, #551edd);
    background-color: currentColor;
    -webkit-mask: url(/images/logo.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;

  background: linear-gradient(358deg, #dd851e, #551edd);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 33s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimationName 33s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: AnimationName 33s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 33s ease infinite;
}


.bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg_item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: opacity 6000ms ease;
}

.bg_item:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url(/images/first.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.bg_item:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(/images/second.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}


@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 99%}
    50%{background-position:100% 2%}
    100%{background-position:0% 99%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 99%}
    50%{background-position:100% 2%}
    100%{background-position:0% 99%}
}
@-o-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 99%}
    50%{background-position:100% 2%}
    100%{background-position:0% 99%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 99%}
    50%{background-position:100% 2%}
    100%{background-position:0% 99%}
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  /*max-width:400px;*/
}
body {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Is Express serving SVG with the correct MIME type? Check the Net tab in your browser dev tools. Also see: https://tomasmcguinness.com/2011/07/06/adding-support-for-svg-to-iis-express/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you for the informative article. While it deals specifically with IIS (and I am on Node and Apache) the concept is the same. With Node, I was not getting a 403 for the SVG. I did check the mozilla site and while there was no indication this would work, I changed: -webkit-mask: url(/images/logo.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%; to  -webkit-mask-image: url(/images/logo.svg); and the svg appeared.... not sure why.